# Visual studio 2019 Team explorer cannot add Local Git Repo when repo is located on protected network drive

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019, team-explorer, git-for-windows

On windows 10 environment:
I have a git repo on a shared location which is only accessible to me. The path of the repo is

\servername\users$\myusername\GitRepo

here "GitRepo" is the folder with source code.

When I try to add his local git repo using visual studio team explorer, I get below error.

Team Explorer error: *No new repositories were found. Errors were encountered while searching for repositories. See the Output window for details.*

Output window: *Errors encountered while searching for repositories:
Git failed with a fatal error.
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory*

For any other network drive or local C drive I do not have a problem. Only the protected network location I get an error. Any input? Any way to get details on the fatal error?

Comment: Can you map a drive letter to it and use that?

Comment: I have tried mapping to a drive letter but it still fails. Not sure if this is some kind of permission issue. The error message is not elaborate.